# Can I pass a mysqli prepared statement into a function?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

After I prepare mysqli statement, and bind parameters to it, can I pass this object to a function?
For example code like this

```
$prepSQL = "DELETE FROM tbl_limit_rates 
        WHERE prod_code = ? AND prod_type = ? AND prod_rate = ?";

$stmtDelLimO = $mysqli->prepare($prepSQL);
$stmtDelLimO->bind_param("isd", $prodCode, $prodType, $prodRate);

$prodCode = 2;
$prodType = "Food";
$prodRate = "15.4";
$quatity = 0;

$test = adjustLimit($quantity, $stmtDelLimO);
echo $test;

function adjustLimit ($quantity, $stmtDelLimO)
{
    if ($quantity == 0) 
    {
         $stmtDelLimo->execute();
         return true;
    }
    else
    {
         return false;
    }
}
```

The function is not working and I am not sure if it's even allowed to use it like this or if I have some other error.

Comment: so we just should just GUESS what this function does? and then there's `$quatity` there... `$qua(N)tity`, perhaps?

Comment: Marc, my question is about the concept. Can you pass that object to a function or not? If you can't, then there is no need trying to find the error. The function is long, that's why i didn't put it there. But it's not important.

Comment: Yes, you can. You can pass anything you want as a parameter. It's how you USE that passed thing that counts.

Comment: ok, i edited it. So, should that work?

Comment: Why don't you just try it? It's not like the universe will implode if it doesn't.

Comment: Well, it's not working. I don't think it's correct conceptually. Because the variables that it's bound to are set outside the function. So, when i execute it inside the function, there are no variables to be bound to it.

Comment: simple test: make sure those variables are defined at the topmost/global scope, then make them `global` within the function...